# No such property com.eriwen.gradle.js.JsHintExtension_Decorated

Tags: javascript, gradle, jshint

I'm trying to include jshint to project and got the error:
    No such property: source for class: com.eriwen.gradle.js.JsHintExtension_Decorated

My conf file:

```
    buildscript {

        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
        }

        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/' }
            maven { url 'http://nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
            maven { url 'http://nexus/content/repositories/cura-releases/' }
            maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:2.14.1"
        }
    }
apply from: '../version.gradle'

apply plugin: "com.eriwen.gradle.js"

javascript.source {
    dev {
        js {
            srcDir "admin/src/main/resources/static/js"
            include "**/*.js"
            exclude "admin/src/main/resources/static/js/lib"
        }
    }
}

jshint {
    tasks.jshint.source = javascript.source.dev.js.files
    tasks.jshint.dest = file("${buildDir}/jshint.out")
    tasks.jshint.reporter = 'checkstyle'
    jshint.options = [expr: "true", unused: "true"]
}
```

Can someone explain me what I do wrong?

Comment: Have you configured the paths correctly? Please try to run gradle with `-i` and `-s` switches.

Comment: output - Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: source for class: com.eriwen.gradle.js.JsHintExtension_De
corated